# DocuSign API Captive Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I have been creating DocuSign envelopes using SOAP based API call "CreateAndSendEnvelope".
When I create an envelope using captive recipients into my DocuSign demo account..

1) When I include captive recipient's e-mail address in the SOAP request, would a captive recipient get a signed document back? I am not able to get the signed document back. I get an email with the notification that I signed the document.

2) My session never times out. According to DocuSign documentation, the session times out in 5 minutes and it is a configurable setting. Where should I look at that setting and how should I test the session timeout?

3) When I request recipient token once and if I make the request to get the token within a short period of time, I get an error. After I wait for a few minutes, I am able to retrieve the recipient token fine. Is there a time frame that I should consider while making a request to retrieve the recipient token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  You can control whether or not to include the completed documents in the email through an account setting.  Login to the Console and go to Preferences -> Features, and on that screen you should see an option labeled `"Attached Documents to Completed Envelope Email"`.

[image]

2)  The default session timeout is actually 20 minutes, not 5.  And if you want to change that you need to contact your Account Manager - it's not a setting you have direct access to.

3)  Embedded Sending and Signing URL tokens are only valid for 5 minutes, after which they expire.  At that point you simply need to generate a new URL token for the given recipient.

Comment: Thanks Ergin for your feedback. I do have the setting turned on for "Attach documents to completed envelope email" and I do receive signed document back for remote signers. If the signers are embedded signers, I do not get signed document back.

Comment: I am not even sure if embedded signers are supposed to get the signed document back or not.